# problem in loading table when changing orientations in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have a customers list in a table view, my application supports orientation , I'm changing the frames of the buttons  according to orientation, which I added to the table cell . But the changes are not occurring properly, the changes will be seen when I navigates to another view and I returns back. But not instantly.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) { 

    isLandscape = YES;
    myTableView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    labelTitle.frame = CGRectMake(500, 120, 300, 30);
    accessoryBtnImageView.frame = CGRectMake(870, 46, 58, 58);
}

else
{
    isLandscape = NO;
    myTableView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0,  768,1024);

    labelTitle.frame = CGRectMake(350, 120, 300, 30);
    accessoryBtnImageView.frame = CGRectMake(600, 66, 58, 58);
 }

return YES;     
}
```

I had used this coding in `viewWillAppear` and 
`(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method also but still I'm getting problem, I think I'm doing some where wrong. please any one help me.
Thank You
Praveena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `autoresizingMask` property on the views instead of resizing them manually.

Depending on how you set the resizing mask, you can make the views stick to one side, expand with the super view when the device rotates, etc.

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6) describes how to do it in details.